# How to bind content with JSON in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

All the examples are using fixed data source in the arraycontroller.content, while I am using dynamic data source which is generated from anther web service and returns a JSON, it won't create an object that I declared in Ember,
here is the code sample:

```
        ET.AppYear = Ember.Object.extend({
            text:null,
            value:null
        });
        ET.EmailTypes = Ember.Object.extend();

        ET.appYearController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
            content: [],
            loadYears: function (year) {
                if (year != null) {
                    for (var i = -5; i < 5; i++) {
                        this.pushObject({ text: year + i, value: year + i });
                       //.AppYear.create({ text: year + i, value: year + i });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ET.selectedAppYearController = Ember.Object.create({
            selectedAppYear: '2011',
            alertChange: function(){
                alert("selected App Year is now " + this.get('selectedAppYear'));
            }.observes('selectedAppYear'),
            isChanged: function () {
                if (this.appYear != null) {
                    this.set('selection',this.get('content'));
                    //LoadETByAppYearETTypeID(this.selectedAppYear, ET.selectedEmailTypesController.emailType.email_template_type_id);
                }
            } .observes('selectedAppYear'),
            AppYear: function() {
                var ay = ET.appYearController.findProperty('text',this.get('selectedAppYear'));
                return ay;
            }.property('selectedAppYear')                
        });
```

As you can see, I will call `ET.appYearController.loadYears`(JSON) in an AJAX post back, which will create the content by using `this.pushObject`, but this is not the `ET.AppYear` object schema, while I call `ET.selectedAppYearController.selectedAppYear`, it returns an undefined object, and which really returns an object with `{text:xx,value,xx}` schema. That's why the `selectionBinding` also won't work in this case.

So what's the typical solution for this to import JSON elements as defined object and put into content?!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the Ember-data library, it was made for your use-case and related use-cases:

https://github.com/emberjs/data

Comment: Ember Data is still in beta, but it is being used in production applications.

Answer (score 5):

**[2014-02-19: Deprecated - I no longer support ember-rest because it is overly simplistic, and would recommend using ember-data for most ember projects. Check out [the Ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/) for an overview of ember-data as well as this [example project](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example) ]**

I've created a very simple library to handle working with REST interfaces from Ember:
https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest

I'm also writing a series of posts about using this library from Rails. The first is here:
http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/01/24/beginning-ember-js-on-rails-part-1/

My next post, hopefully coming later today, deals precisely with loading data via AJAX into a collection of Ember objects. For now, you can see this behavior in the sample app as well as the ember-rest.js readme.

If you'd like to avoid using this lib, you might still want to check out the source. The `deserialize()` method on `Ember.Resource` is used to import JSON and could also be used with a generic `Ember.Object`.