# What is the best way to populate an ember object with JSON data coming from an AJAX call (XHR request)?

Tags: ember.js

We have an ember object, which we want to populate with data coming from an AJAX call:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create(
    { rootElement: '#container' }
);

App.WindowDetail = Ember.Object.create({
        ID: "",
        Title: "",
InteriorFinishesDescription: ""

});
```

Currently, we are getting JSON data via an AJAX call in this manner:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        //Call the page method   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TestController.aspx",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
            data: "asaw",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {

               App.WindowDetail.InteriorFinishesDescription = r.InteriorFinishesDescription;

                alert(App.WindowDetail.InteriorFinishesDescription);

            }
        });
    });
```

In this sample, the JSON data comes back fine -- "App.WindowDetail.InteriorFinishesDescription" gets populated.

The problem is that the template doesn't get populated. And, I don't think this is exactly the correct way to get JSON data back when using Ember JS.

Here's a sample of what the handlebars template looks like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <div class="two columns">
      {{App.WindowDetail.InteriorFinishesDescription}}
   </div> 
</script>
```

Comment: I think that I have found a direction and possible answer to my own question: Ember Resource, https://github.com/staugaard/ember-resource. Thanks to Dan Gebhardt (http://stackoverflow.com/users/664735/dan-gebhardt) for his answer to a post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020614/how-to-bind-content-with-json-in-ember-js/9022905#9022905)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to trigger Ember's bindings, you'll need to use set():

```
App.WindowDetail.set("InteriorFinishesDescription", r.InteriorFinishesDescription);
```

BTW, I'm glad you found my other answer helpful. There are definitely a few different persistence options out there. In terms of complexity and capability, I'd say they go from jQuery.ajax() to [Ember REST](https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest) to [Ember Resource](https://github.com/staugaard/ember-resource) to [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data).

Comment: Ah, set(). Thanks! As you can see, I'm just getting started learning ember.

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the question as answered (if it has been, that is) to be clear to others -- thanks.

Comment: Great answer Dan. Maybe set the link to your "other answer". I am just trying to put the persistent layer on the client side in my app and I find still rather difficult to find information, examples and tutorials. But I think I am getting there, your work is very helpful :)

Comment: Thanks Aras :) If you're interested in ember-data as well, I've just updated an example to work with the latest ember & ember-data: https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example